# ¿Cómo enviar datos a otra pagina de forma automatica con ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Amigos necesito conectar datos de una pagina a otra sin recargar la pagina y de forma automática he tratado con el siguiente codigo buscando que una vez se recargue la pagina se llene  la variable de la pagina procesobusqueda.ph que la tengo asi.
$correousuario=$_POST['correo'];

Esta es la libreria que estoy usando con otros ajax e funciona perfectamente.

este es el input que tengo donde se encontrara el correo.

```
<input type="text" id="usuario1"  value="<?php echo$correousuario?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload=function(){
  var correo=document.getElementById('usuario1?>').value;
                      var dato="correo="+correo;
                  $.ajax({
                        url:'procesobusqueda.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:dato,
                      })
                      .done(function(res){
                          $('.resultadobusqueda').html(res)
                            
                      })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: La línea `getElementById('usuario1?>')` tiene un error, `?>` no debería estar, prueba quitando eso. Por otro lado, te recomiendo ordenar un poco más el código, ser más estricto con la sintaxis de PHP, por ejemplo, hay un `echo` que no tiene espacio entre función y variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He editado tu código ordenándolo un poco, con eso debería funcionar correctamente:

```
<input type="text" id="usuario1"  value="<?php echo $correousuario ?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload=function(){
   var correo=document.getElementById('usuario1').value;
   var dato="correo="+correo;
       $.ajax({
           url:'procesobusqueda.php',
           type:'POST',
           data:dato,
       })
   .done(function(res){
        $('.resultadobusqueda').html(res)                
   })
  }
</script>
```